# Nullspace of Original Matrix multiplied by Transpose

Tags: matrices, transpose

I need help in a question. I need to show that, given an $ m \times n$ matrix $A$, $\bar x \in Null(A)$ if and only if $\bar x \in Null(A^tA)$.

I found this answer:
"Let $X=Null(A)$; then $\forall x \in X, Ax=0$. Assume that $Y=Null(A^tA)$, i.e. $\forall y \in Y, A^t Ay=0$. This implies, $Ay=0$ or $A^tAy=0$ and $Ay \ne 0$. If case (1) is true than we are done: $y \in X$. Now $A^tAy=0 \implies y^tA^tA = 0^t \implies y^tA^t = 0^T$ so (since $A \ne 0$) $Ay=0$. And this is same as case (1). Thus $X=Y$."

But how does this show that it is "if and only if"?

Comment: If you have made any progress on the proof, you should include your work so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "only if" part is really trivial:

$x\in Null(A)$ implies $A^tAx=A^t0=0$.

I don´t know where You found this answer to the if part, but it´s weird, try:

If $y\in Null(A^tA)$ then $A^tAy=0$, by definition and thus $|Ay|^2=y^tA^tAy=y^t0=0$ and thus $Ay=0$, since |.| is a norm, i.e. $y\in Null(A)$